# I see a value 1E19 on my Oracle table with number column

Tags: oracle, numbers

I see a value 1E19 on my Oracle table with number column. When I try to insert this value to another column marked number(20,5), it fails. If I see the length, it says 1E19 has a length of 19, so that's the reason for the failure (>15).
So is the value of 1E19 = 1 followed by 18 zeros. How do i see the literal value in Oracle?

Comment: Okey, i got the answer, to_char gives me the answer, its 19 9s, so it can be any 19 digits,IMO

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a SQL Session value from NUMWIDTH to hold the columns values.

```
SQL> SET NUMWIDTH 40
SQL> SELECT n
  2  FROM   t
  3  WHERE  n BETWEEN 12345678901234567800
  4               AND 12345678901234567900
  5  /
                                    N
----------------------------------------
                12345678901234567890
```

This should help you:

http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/9660/2/